# Can I write Silverlight apps for Windows CE in .NET?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-ce

I've seen that Windows CE 6 R3 has Silverlight support, but that it differs from the Silverlight support on Windows Phone 7 in that it only supports native C++ code. Is there any way to get around that? If I have written a Silverlight app for WP7 in .net, can I translate that into an unmanaged app (or unmanaged C++ code) that can run on Windows CE?

Thanks in advance!

Kris

Answer (score 2):

The Windows CE Silverlight support is C++-only, and porting from other managed apps is not very easy.  Lots of features differ, some are missing from the C++ version, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I found a presentation by Andy Wigley from TechEd 2010, where he shows a way to write your application logic in managed code, using the MVP pattern.

You can find the presentation here: http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/WEM309